# SVN - Steps to get all the files from a repository?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

We have an existing repository on the network accessed via HTTP:.

Should I first import these files to my local machine? I tried importing directories, files, etc., everything is empty in my local folders. It says "success", but nothing ever shows up!

It doesn't make sense to create a repository on my side. But all the tutorials seem to say that, but then I think they're assuming you're starting from nothing.

My experience with Tortoise SVN has mostly been negative. Typically whatever I think I should do turns out to be incorrect, and I end up having to undo, and redo, or lose my work. Once I even managed to corrupt the main repository and it had to be restored from backup.

I absolutely cannot damage this existing repository!

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use SVN without much knowledge about it. Start by reading some basics: Creating a Working Copy - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.initial.html#svn.tour.initial

Comment: @IvanJovovic - I agree. So I should checkout all the files? Wouldn't that prevent anyone else from modifying them? Why won't import copy them?

Comment: To get a "working copy" (a copy of the files you can work on) from a repository, you do a "checkout". Once you have a working copy, you can make edits/commit/etc.

Comment: I would also recommend like Ivan does that you read at least some of the svnbook. It is well written and has good information that will be useful.

Comment: *So I should checkout all the files?* - Yes. *Wouldn't that prevent anyone else from modifying them?* - No. *Why won't import copy them?* - Because SVN doesn't work that way. If you copy them, SVN will not be able to track your changes and all the other stuff that CVS is meant to do. Make a coffee/tee/cocktail, and start reading SVN basics :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're used to CVS or some older version control systems, note that SVN uses the same terms differently. In those, checkout often means lock in exclusive mode.

In SVN checkout will make a copy and automatically manage the revisions and help you merge from multiple sources. You don't need to lock a file, unless it's graphical or some other binary where merging doesn't make sense.

So in TortoiseSVN, you can checkout, and edit the files. The icons on the files will change to indicate their status.

SVN is easy in comparison to git, where the same terms are again redefined and significantly augmented!